# WCF not decoding parameters on WebGet method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a .NET 4.5 WCF service. On my localhost and one other server the method parameters are passed correctly. However, on a different server, the method parameters remain encoded.

For example, if I use the following:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<MyService.Interface.ILeadService>("MyService", new EndpointAddress(url));
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)channel))
{
    channel.AddCalendarItem("09/26/2013 7:40PM");
}
```

To call this method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "AddCalendarItem/?startDate={startDate}",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
AddCalendarItemResponse AddCalendarItem(string startDate);
```

On my local (Windows 8) machine and one server (Windows Server 2008 R2) I get the expected string: **"09/26/2013 7:40PM"**

However, on one server (Windows Server 2012) with the same code and configuration I get: **"09%2f26%2f2013 9%3a30PM"**

I can't tell if the problem is with the caller or the callee.

Any idea what could be causing the lack of decoding?
Could the channel be double-encoding?

Comment: any solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

What is Lead there?

Try now, it should work,

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "/AddCalendarItem/{token}?startDate={startDate}")]
        AddCalendarItemResponse AddCalendarItem(string token, string startDate);
```

Comment: Sorry Sajeetharan, that was a typo when posting. After more research I determined that the issue is actually happening not from the browser but from a different client service so I updated my question.